I don't understand, how the given pointers are working in C
I'm learning C by reading books about. There was a listing to show some concepts. In this case type-casts. After I copied the listing and ran the program I got an output which I don't understand
int main(){
    float value = 65.78;
    float  *flt_ptr = &value;
    char *ch_ptr = (char*) &value;

    printf("type-cast (char*) flt_ptr: %c\n", (char*) flt_ptr); // line 1
    printf("type-cast (char) *flt_ptr: %c\n", (char) *flt_ptr); // line 2
    printf("type-cast (char*) ch_ptr: %c\n", (char*) ch_ptr); // line 3
    printf("type-cast (char) *ch_ptr: %c\n", (char) *ch_ptr); // line 4

    return 0;
}

As outputted values I get the lines:

line 1 and 3: some non interpretable, because memory addresses in char are senseless and unknown by the ASCII-table
line 2 gives an "A" with the converted integer 65. So far so good.
line 4 outputs "" which has the converted value 92
When I convert these values to binary the first 8 bits (the size of the pointer on which its pointing) of 65 are identical to the first 8 bits of my floating number 65.78. But the first 8 bits of the binary value of 92 are different to the floating number. I don't understand which part of my memory i am reading and why I'm reading another part of my memory in this printf()-line?
I thought every pointer in this program is pointing at the same address, but the size they're pointing on is different. But than the converted binaries had to be identical but they aren't.


This line does not compile when I try your code: char *ch_ptr = (char''') &value;  I get "error C2137: empty character constant".  I am using Visual Studio 2022 C++ compiler.  I get several other compile errors as well.

You are effectively seeing undefined behaviour, as you are trying to express floating point numbers (or part thereof) as characters. A floating point number in computers is not stored as a serieis of characters like "65.78" (five characters). It is held as a pair of binary values, the first part being the exponent (power of 2), and the second the mantissa, or value. The fact that one part apears to be the value 65, or "A", is just a coincidence. So all those print statements above are totally meaningless.

char *ch_ptr = (char''') &value; isn't valid C.  Did you mean char *ch_ptr = (char *) &value; instead?

What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C? Follow that advise so you don't need to waste time troubleshooting bugs that the compiler has already found and reported.

@OldBoy Rather, they are passing pointers when they should be passing characters. "Line 1" and "line 3" need to be dereferenced.

line 1 and 3: A pointer is a number, it cannot be interpreted as a char, too tiny to contains this number. You're trying to display as a char only a part of the pointer. You must use %p to display a pointer.
line 4: You're trying to access the memory of a float as a char. Here also only a part of the float is accessed, and it is an "Undefined Behavior" (dereferencing a pointer on not its real type), anything can happen.

@OldBoy Line 2 is not a coincidence. It retrieves the floating-point value (65.78), then casts it to a byte-sized integer character value (65) which gets displayed as A. Line 3 is UB, because the data is not necessarily a null-terminated byte string.

@OldBoy: The bit string for an IEEE-754 binary floating-point representation has three fields, not two: The sign bit, the biased exponent, and the significand. (“Significand” is the preferred term; “mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm.) The fact that “A” is printed is not a coincidence; converting the float value for 65.78 to char truncates the value, producing 65, and printing that using ASCII prints “A”.

@Dúthomhas You are correct, but it is not something that one should ever rely on.

@EricPostpischil Sorry, I knew I had missed something, and of course it was the sign. And yes, it happens to print the 65 as an A but it really is not something that anyone should be using in their programs.

@OldBoy There are very strict and well-defined rules about casting from float to int in C. (char) *p_float is perfectly valid.


(char''') &value; is nonsense and invalid C so the code will not even compile on a standard C compiler.

(char*) flt_ptr and (char*) ch_ptr are nonsense since you cannot pass a pointer to printf where it expects a character through %c. You invoke undefined behavior so anything can happen - the strange output isn't necessarily caused by "memory addresses in char are senseless", but rather because you lied to printf and told it you'd pass a character, then passed something else entirely.

 (char*) ch_ptr is nonsense since it casts from a char* to char*.

(char) *ch_ptr is nonsense since it casts from a char to a char.


So you have quite a bit of conceptual problems here.

That aside, we have to realize the difference between (char)some_float and *(char*)&some_float. Either is valid C but the two examples do very different things.
With (char)some_float, char is treated just like any of the integer types, so it is pretty much the same thing as writing (int)some_float. What happens here is that we tell the compiler to helpfully reinterpret our float number into a fixed point format, which is done by discarding the decimals. In this case you will end up with 65. Any integer 65 printed with %c will result in 'A' indeed, given the most common symbol tables (ASCII/UTF8). That's what you got when you did (char) *flt_ptr.
But in case of *(char*)&some_float we tell the compiler to take the float address and treat what's stored there as an array of characters, which we can access through a character pointer. The left-most * in my example is dereferencing the first byte of the float. Here you stumbled upon a very special feature of C which only works when we go from pointer-to-anything to pointer-to-character. The purpose of this is to allow us to do hardware-related programming and inspect the raw binary contents of any object, byte by byte. Hence character type, because a character is C's type used for representing a byte.
So we end up with the raw binary representation of the float, which will just be gibberish if printed as %c. Because the raw binary will be IEEE 754 floating point with sign bit, exponent and fraction parts. How float numbers are stored in memory is a whole chapter of its own.
This is now turning into a more advanced topic:
In case we do want to print the binary representation of a float with printf, we better use unsigned char since the char type may or may not be a signed integer type depending on compiler.
We may try this code:
unsigned char *ch_ptr = (unsigned char*) &value; 

for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(float); i++)
{
  printf("%.2X ", ch_ptr[i]);
}

This gives us the output 5C 8F 83 42. 0x5C being the 92 you spotted. The raw binary representation of 65.78 can be conveniently obtained from a site like https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html. The actual number stored isn't 100% accurate since we are dealing with float numbers. But we should be expecting 42838f5c when translated to hex. And that's the numbers we just got, but backwards. Backwards because I used an Intel x86 computer, which utilizes little endian, meaning I get the least significant byte first - why it appears backwards when printed byte by byte starting at the lowest address.

We should note that casting a pointer to a different type in C and then de-reference it is not OK in most cases however. That's an advanced topic where things like alignment and C's underlying type system come into play, as well as issues regarding const correctness etc.


printf("type-cast (char*) flt_ptr: %c\n", (char*) flt_ptr); // line 1

This passes a char * for a %c. For %c, printf expects to receive an int, which it will convert to an unsigned char and print. The behavior of this is not defined by the C standard. In many circumstances, it will print the low byte of the pointer as an unsigned char.

printf("type-cast (char) *flt_ptr: %c\n", (char) *flt_ptr); // line 2

*flt_ptr retrieves the value of the float, about 65.78 (exactly 65.779998779296875 when the IEEE-754 binary32 format is used for float). Then (char) converts this to a char. Converting a floating-point value to an integer truncates it, producing 65. When the C implementation uses ASCII, this will print “A”.

printf("type-cast (char*) ch_ptr: %c\n", (char*) ch_ptr); // line 3

As in line 1, this passes a char * for %c.

printf("type-cast (char) *ch_ptr: %c\n", (char) *ch_ptr); // line 4

Since ch_ptr has been set to point to value (after correcting the typo in (char''') to (char *), *ch_ptr retrieves the first byte of value. This is a byte of the encoding of the float value into bits in memory. The encoding used for float is a bit involved and is discussed in other Stack Overflow questions. As it happens, the first byte has the value 92, which, in ASCII, stands for the backslash character, “\”, so that is printed.
